# How can I get a lined-text only in a few parts of the text? (please refer to figure in attachment)

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

I would like to have some parts of my text with the following background (like the attached figure). How can I do this??

I believe is something relatively easy. Hope someone could help me with that.[image: Desired output]
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution with `multido`  and `setspace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace, multido} 
\newcommand{\Lines}[1]{\begin{spacing}{1.25}\parindent=0pt\mbox{}\multido{\i =1+1}{#1}{\mbox{}\hrulefill\\\mbox{}}%
\vskip-0.8\baselineskip
\end{spacing}}

 \begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\Lines{6}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]